# basic http auth in zappier code

Tags: javascript, api, integration, fetch-api, zapier

I'm trying to send HTTP request with Zapier Code to hit my API to do some GET and POST requests.

[image]

API requires **API_KEY** in form of **authorization** header to understand my requests. Here is code I'm running

```
 var settings = {
      "url": "https://<HOST>/api/v1/siteinfo",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Basic <TOKEN>",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }

fetch(settings.url, settings)
.then(function (r) {
  callback({data: r});
}).catch(callback);
```

But get this error:

[image]

**What is wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the first argument of **callback** function is always error, thus if we have the some result to pass from asynchronous action we should pass `null` as the first argument to `callback`, e.g. in my case I should have this:

```
fetch(settings.url, settings)
.then(function (r) {
  callback(null, {data: r});
}).catch(callback);
```