# How to provide basic HTTP authentication in Zapier code?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, zapier

Documentation provides simple examples with fetch API:

```
fetch('http://example.com/')
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    var output = {id: 1234, rawHTML: body};
    callback(null, output);
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

to query data.

**How can I add headers or pass post data in those structures?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [basic http auth in zappier code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934030/basic-http-auth-in-zappier-code)

Answer (score 0):

One can use standard Fetch API possibilities (second parameter is options for request where you can pass headers, HTTP method to be used etc.), e.g.

```
var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: {
                authentication: 'Basic lkjbwkejbf...'
               },
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };

fetch('flowers.jpg', myInit).then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```

like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)